# How can I restore a snapshot on an existing Elasticache cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have an application where I deploy a Elasticache cluster with one node (for my use case having multi AZ is not an option considering the costs). If the node goes down for some reason, the data is lost and I want to use the snapshot from previous day to restore it.

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups.html) says

"Amazon ElastiCache clusters running Redis can back up their data. The backup can be used to restore a cluster or seed a new cluster."

But there are no instructions on how to restore a cluster. They have also provided a page which says "[Restoring From a Backup with Optional Cluster Resizing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-restoring.html)", but if you read the instructions, they explain how to restore a new cluster not an existing one. I don't see any related options in the console or API.

Am I missing something here ? If there is a way to do this please let me know. Only other way I can think about this is to populate the data into the cluster manually with a script which reads the backup ".rdb" file.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no way to restore the data to the existing cluster. The backups, which are taken by means of the snapshot, are restored only through the new cluster.